# Command line regular expression '*' and python sys.argv

Tags: python, regex

I have a folder with a number of files that are different by one number (foo1.inp, foo2.inp, foo3.inp, ...).  I want to pass to python, using command line arguments and sys.argv, a string like 'foo*.inp' so I can glob a list of all the files.  However, the argument passed to python when I execute python script.py foo*.inp, ends up being whatever file is listed first in the folder: foo1.inp, instead of foo*.inp.

How can I do this correctly?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your *shell* interprets unquoted wildcards...but it's probably doing exactly what you want.  Why not just use all of `sys.argv` instead of the first argument?

Comment: You're right, I just need a list with all the files names.  I didn't stop to think that now my sys.argv is going to contain all the file names. I just was focused on sys.argv[1], where I was expecting to find 'foo*.inp'.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
python myscript.py "foo*.inp"
```

I think should work (and not expand your glob)

otherwise as mentioned in the comments its your shell that is expanding foo*.inp to a list of files and then passing them to your script ... and your shell will always do that ... the solution is to quote the glob pattern (it is not regex...) assuming that you actually want the glob pattern and not the files it matches